# Difference global variable in class difference variable in method

Tags: java

I was wondering what might be good side of writing need variable as global in service and difference local varible in the method. What might be good or bad? For example

```
@Service
public class OfficeCodeImpl implements OfficeCodeService {

    @Autowired
    private OfficeCodeRepository officeCodeRepository;

    private List<OfficeCodeDto> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private OfficeCodeEntity officeCodeEntity = new OfficeCodeEntity();

    @Override
    public List<OfficeCodeDto> getAll() {
        officeCodeRepository.findAll().forEach(i ->{
             OfficeCodeDto officeCodeDto = new OfficeCodeDto();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(i,officeCodeDto);
            list.add(officeCodeDto);
         });
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(OfficeCodeDto officeCodeDto) {
       BeanUtils.copyProperties(officeCodeDto,officeCodeEntity);
       officeCodeRepository.save(officeCodeEntity);
    }
    


}
```

For me I understand that when you call this class only you need method will declare all varible that inside of this method. If you implement it as global variable it will generate new value if this all varible you need all not need.

```
@Service
public class OfficeCodeImpl implements OfficeCodeService {

    @Autowired
    private OfficeCodeRepository officeCodeRepository;




    @Override
    public List<OfficeCodeDto> getAll() {
        List<OfficeCodeDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        officeCodeRepository.findAll().forEach(i ->{
             OfficeCodeDto officeCodeDto = new OfficeCodeDto();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(i,officeCodeDto);
            list.add(officeCodeDto);
         });
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(OfficeCodeDto officeCodeDto) {
        OfficeCodeEntity officeCodeEntity = new OfficeCodeEntity();
       BeanUtils.copyProperties(officeCodeDto,officeCodeEntity);
       officeCodeRepository.save(officeCodeEntity);
    }



}
```

Difference this two code ?

Comment: Is there an aspect of the behaviour of the two code samples above which you don't understand? Please tell us exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second approach.

In the first case, if you call `getAll` twice, the same element might be added into the list twice, so you might get the wrong result.